# How does the locking mechanism work for these doors?

Tags: doors, lock, pull

Below is an example of such door, where there is no handle that you can twist.  There is only a fixed handle, and a place to insert the key to lock the door.

[image]

***The question.*** If you leave the house, with the door unlocked, and decide to re-enter the house without having the key, then how will you open the door?   With a classical door, you rotate a moving handle.  But with these, the handle doesn't seem to be rotateable.

Comment: A picture of the latch in the lock and unlock positions would help some.  Off hand it sounds more like a dead bolt idea than a latch type idea.

Comment: @crip659 - I'm new to this.  Any idea how dead-bolt-only doors keep close when not locked?

Comment: @caveman maybe they don't

Comment: maybe it has a roller latch ... https://www.ironmongeryworld.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/d/adjustable_roller_brass_1.jpg

Comment: I have similar doors that only use a deadbolt.  Since the doors are exterior, the doors are pretty tight fitting.  They have a button detent on the top edge that helps keep the door closed when not locked.  But with any heavy wind, the door will blow open if not locked.

Comment: @Programmer66 - Pics/links for such a _button detent_ please?

Comment: Give me a minute,  adding link ... <a hef="https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-Satin-Nickel-Latch-Adjustable-Ball-Catch-15389/202045104?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=Shopping-B-F_D25H-G-D25H-025_004_BUILDER_HARD-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-BuildersHardware_Smart_Q3_Pro_Control&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D25H-G-D25H-025_004_BUILDER_HARD-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-BuildersHardware_Smart_Q3_Pro_Control-71700000081230576-58700006913855557-92700064304424110&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8NzdzrSg8wIV_yCtBh3I9AtlEAQYAyABEgI5CfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds">ball catch</a>

Comment: @Programmer66 - I'd appreciate if you add it as an answer, too.  So that I accept it.

Comment: You've accepted an answer, but a picture of the latch itself would still help to improve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have doors like these that are closed and locked by a deadbolt.

Per the other posters,  the lock is a deadbolt, which uses a key on the outside, and the inside can either be a key or knob.  If you leave the house without a key, it cannot be locked except from the inside.

The door is kept closed when unlocked, by devices such as these [Ball Catch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-Satin-Nickel-Latch-Adjustable-Ball-Catch-15389/202045104?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=Shopping-B-F_D25H-G-D25H-025_004_BUILDER_HARD-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-BuildersHardware_Smart_Q3_Pro_Control&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D25H-G-D25H-025_004_BUILDER_HARD-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-BuildersHardware_Smart_Q3_Pro_Control-71700000081230576-58700006913855557-92700064304424110&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8NzdzrSg8wIV_yCtBh3I9AtlEAQYAyABEgI5CfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).  These ball catches are placed on the top edge or the opening edge to provide fiction to hold the door close.

In a heavy wind, the door may still be blown open

per the other question -

> The question. If you leave the house, with the door unlocked, and decide
> to re-enter the house without having the key, then how will you open the
> door? With a classical door, you rotate a moving handle. But with these,
> the handle doesn't seem to be rotatable.

The door is held shut by the catch ball, to open you just push on the handle or door.

Comment: Nice, thanks.  Thinking of improvements.. How about [magnet-based](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmQbYyj6eRo) ones?  [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3idyE94Dohw) is speaking against the ball catches.

Comment: Mine has been in use for over 40 years without any issues,  they are hidden.  As you can see from the video from your link for the use of a magnet catch, he is using them on an interior door with the magnet clearly visible on the door frame.  This would not look good on that expensive door.  The ball catch holds pretty tight, but a heavy wind generates a lot of pressure on a door.  You could make the ball catch hold higher by putting in a heavier spring behind the ball.  The door you are looking at would most likely have the ball catch already installed.

Comment: On the bright side, the magnet catch _could_ be part of a smart home installation that notifies you when the door is open.

Answer (score 1):

Some doors have no latch-handle on one side requiring a key to be used to retract the latch.

> The question. If you leave the house, with the door unlocked, and decide to re-enter the house without having the key, then how will you open the door? With a classical door, you rotate a moving handle. But with these, the handle doesn't seem to be rotateable.

If you latched the door behind you then you are out of luck and need to call someone on the inside, find a (person with a) back-up key or call a locksmith. With a door like that you should have the habit of always having your keys with you to avoid that scenario.

If you want to leave the house without a key and reenter later then you need to prop open the door with a door-stop to prevent wind from slamming it. Sometimes you can leave the door resting against the latch but a strong draft can still overcome that resistance and latch it closed.

Comment: Any examples of such door-stoppers that hold the door in place when in closed position?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if the door was not lucked by the key, a push-button will retrieve the tongue to the unlocked position, a slight blow of air will open the door.  If it is locked by key, the button is locked as well.